# Dynamic HTML form input depending on SQL query results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have an HTML form that allows users to enter a nickname and choose a gender to connect.

### Code

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="start" method="post">
  <fieldset>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="nickname">Nickname</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="nickname" name="nickname" type="text" class="form-control" required="required">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="gender">Gender</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
            <input type="radio" name="username" value="Female" id="username"> <i class="fa fa-female"></i> Female
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
            <input type="radio" name="username" value="Male" id="username"> <i class="fa fa-male"></i> Male
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="button"></label>
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button id="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Enter</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </fieldset>
  </form>
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Question

Once the `nickname` input field has been completed by the user, I want to run a SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(u.id) FROM users u WHERE u.nickname = **value_of_input_field**
```

if the SQL result is `>0`:

then a `password` input field should magically appear between the `nickname` and `gender` fields.

How on earth can I accomplish this?

I have no idea where to even start looking or what to look for, so any pointers, suggestions etc. are very welcome but code examples would be even better.

Comment: AJAX. Use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for the server side processing and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/show/) for the _magically appear_

Comment: UI might be a little too heavy for the *magically appear* @Reeno, the OP just needs one input to appear.

Comment: You would want to write a php file that connects to the db, runs your query, then echos the mysql_num_rows. Then you would use a jquery trigger to say when there is a value change in the nickname field, run ajax against the php file and return the data. Then if the data is indeed greater than 0, use jquery to remove the "display: none" css from the password field

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I didnt test this but I think if it doesnt work, it is close enough to get you going.

You would have a css class

```
.hiding{
    display: none;
}
```

Your html snippet would look something like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="nickname" type="text" id="nickname">
    <input name="password" type="text" id="password" class="hiding">
    <input> <!-- other buttons and form elements -->
</form>
```

The js would look something like this (assuming you have included jquery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //other jquery/js stuff

        $("#nickname").change(function(){
            var nick = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    nickname: nick
                },
                url: "actions/validate.php",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data){
                    if(data>0){
                        $("#password").removeClass("hiding");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the php would look something like this

```
<?php
    //connect to db

    $nickname= $_POST["nickname"];

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(u.id) FROM users u WHERE u.nickname = '".$nickname."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo $numRows;

    //disconnect to db
?>
```